# Execute script for mongo

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go-driver

I'd like to write some Mongo db scripts to update schema of my database while I change version of my program, developed in Go.

While I think I could write this scripts in `Go`, I'd like to produce them as `script.js`, since I think they will be even more readable and they will have to be unchanged once written.

How can I execute a script for Mongo via [mongo-go-driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver)?

Comment: You can use golang's [exec package](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/) to run external commands from within go.

Comment: @prasad_ while `exec` is for sure a solution, I would not use the already established connection and I should write an ad hoc solution, check the error differently etc.
But it's the only solution I think if the library doesn't have one.

Comment: An option is you can run the MongoDB native _commands_ (e.g., create an index using the database command [createIndex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/createIndexes/)) using driver API.

Comment: @prasad_ but I'd like to run script written strictly separated from Go!